# How to upload image from iOS to DropBox using incoming Image url?

Tags: ios, dropbox-api, alassetslibrary

I am working with an iOS application in which i have to upload a selected image on dropbox.
i am getting the url of image with its id as below-

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=36BF5BC0-09A7-4F77-837D-460BD7DF2580&ext=JPG
```

now i have to upload that image by using this url of selected image.i am using the below method ,but i am not getting the right way to upload the image with incoming url::

```
 NSString* filename = dropboximagepath;  //i am storing the image url in dropboximagepath

  NSString* destDir = @"";

   NSString* srcPath = @"/";

[self.restClient uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:srcPath];
```

please tell me that which filename & fromPath value i will use so that my image will upload on dropbox.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the parameters backwards.

You should pass the local path to the file into the `fromPath` parameter, so something like this:

```
[self.restClient uploadFile:@"photo.jpg"
                     toPath:@"/"
              withParentRev:nil
                   fromPath:dropboximagepath];
```

This will create a file called "photo.jpg" in the root of the user's Dropbox.